# how to looping array string with increment on table

Tags: php, html, native

I have an array like this

```
$Peringkat = array("Pertama","Ke-dua","Ke-tiga","Ke-empat","Ke-Lima");
```

and a table like this

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered text-center">
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Nis</th>
        <th>Nama</th>
        <th>Kelas</th>
        <th>Nilai Rata-rata</th>
        <th>Nama Sekolah</th>
        <th>Peringkat</th>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach ($Peringkat as $key => $value) {
     while ($baris = $sql->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $n++ ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $baris['nis'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $baris['nama_siswa'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $baris['nama_kelas'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $baris['Hasil'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $baris['nama_sekolah'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value ; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } }?>
</table>
```

How would I make a loop in ascending order to the value of the data string?

Comment: You have 2 loops in your code (`foreach` and `while`) so I don't know which loop your question refers to: which data do you want in ascending value?

Comment: I need 2 loops, 1. loop while for get data from database 2. set data string from array $peringkat to describe a row on table

Comment: Ok I showed you how in my answer.

Comment: all rows remain the same value "pertama"

Answer (score 0):

To sort your array of strings in ascending order, use `asort`

```
$Peringkat = array("Pertama","Ke-dua","Ke-tiga","Ke-empat","Ke-Lima");
asort($Peringkat); //ascending order
```

Now you can proceed as before.

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/kQ8co)

Note that if you sort `$Peringkat`, your table rows will be the same as before with the only difference being the last cell of each row.  Depending on the nature of your `$sql` data, this could result in a mismatch.

Comment: solutions such as what if I want to display the data like this

http://pastebin.com/JJczGHRq